# Remove Backtick From String

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am using the [npm 'mysql'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) for a Node app I am working on. At one point that app saves a link to a table. In order to add the link to the table I have to use the npm's escapeId() function.

My issue is that when I got to retrieve that link from the database I get something like this:

```
'`http://bit`.`ly/2yy0foe`'
```

I am not having an issue splitting the string at the period. I am having an issue getting rid of the backticks. Any suggestions? Using the npm or any other method.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try anything? There's lots of answers on SO on how to replace characters in a string... It's one of the most common questions, and subsequently, one of the easiest to find an answer to.

Comment: @TimLewis I tried a couple of this, but it looks like another user solved what I was missing. See his answer below.

Comment: I know, it's just the point of SO is to try something, fail, ask for help (while showing your attempts) and learn from you mistake. If you legitimately tried and got stuck then that's fine, but try to show us what you tried, so we don't assume you are just looking for code.

Comment: @TimLewis noted. I was kind of in a rush, but I will remember that for next time. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. No one yelled at you/you didn't get downvoted into oblivion, but it's possible if you don't show effort :P

Comment: Ironically, this post is now the first result when searching for removing a backtick from string. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove the unwanted characters.

```
var newStr = '`http://bit`.`ly/2yy0foe`'.replace(/`/g, "");
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will accept your answer as correct when the system allows me to.